# Issue adding objects to existing classes Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a class in Parse called "Groups", within that class their is a column called "Group Name", there is also a column that contains a relation called "GroupInfo" which contains all the group information for the specific group. I am trying to add more data into an existing column within the "GroupInfo" relation called "Project". Unfortunately, my code does absolutely nothing when I run it. I would appreciate any help on how to get it working.

```
  var group: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Groups")
func uploadscores () {

   group.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: "RK5kQ6feTW")
    group.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && object != nil {
            if let object = object as? [PFObject] {
                for objects in object {
                    let relation = objects.relationForKey("GroupInfo")
                    let query = relation.query()
                    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (obj: [AnyObject]?, err: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if err == nil && obj != nil {
                            if let obj = obj as? [PFObject] {
                                for objs in obj {
                                objs.addObject("Paint the walls", forKey: "Project")

                                }

                            }
                        }

                    })

                }

            }

        }


    }


}







override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    uploadscores()

}
```

Comment: Holy pyramid code, Batman.  I don't know Swift, but add some breakpoints into your code by clicking on the line number in Xcode, then run your project again.  You'll see which lines run and which don't.  And the last one that runs will be one where you're making a call wrong, or not passing in what you think you are.

Comment: You never save any of your changed objects

Answer (score 0):

Just like Paulw11 commentedm you aren't saving your changes on the Parse objects. Use `.saveInBackground` to save the object onto Parse asynchronously:

```
for objs in obj {
    objs.addObject("Paint the walls", forKey: "Project")
    objs.saveInBackground()
}
```